# if statement to print the file name who have either changed or are new

Tags: shell, if-statement, md5

i have some file in my directory like

```
  a.txt
  a.txt.md5
  b.txt
  b.txt.md5
  c.txt
```

and i am trying to write a shell script which will print the name of file of which Md5 is no present or Md5 is changed

like

```
 for filename in ".txt"
 do
   if($filename.md5 not present OR $filename.md5 is changed)
     echo $filename
   fi
 done
```

so how will this if condition be like?

```
  if($filename.md5 not present OR $filename.md5 is changed)
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Debian 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting in a single if statement:

```
is_changed
if [ !-e $file -o $? == 0 ];then
   print $file
fi
```

It assumes that your function is_changed returns 0 if it's changed and something else otherwise.

Comment: can u please help me with the is_changed how will it be like

Comment: $is_changed = md5sum -c $filename.md5 0 1

Comment: just in case if you're wondering where -e and -o comes from, you can read the man page for test: man test

Comment: `-o` is all but deprecated by the POSIX standard, which recommends `if [ ! -e "$file" ] || [ $? = 0 ]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Test if the file exists is easy:

```
if [ -e $file ]; then
   #checksum again
   if [ $? == 0 ];then
       echo $file
   fi
else
    echo $file 
fi
```

I am just abstracting whatever you do to check checksum

perhaps I better add a pseudo code:

```
if file exists
   checksum
   if changed
      print filename
 else
      print filename
```

Comment: cant i write both the condition in one if as in practical i have a long code in place of print filename so the code will be repeated & yes off course i can have function for it but still

Comment: yes you can, but you would have to check if file changed before.

Comment: I will add another answer explaining that because comments are limited